# toggleClass - Parent Sibling Selector - Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just having a couple of issues, with the below script I've made.

It works perfectly in terms of toggling the form panels, however when i then start to interact with the 'Active' panel (ie click a input field), the active class is removed from its parent element, thus minimizing the panel.

```
$(function () {
    $('.options-list li').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can restrict the toggle function to only the title contents?

https://jsfiddle.net/os883y47/

I think its due to the 'Title' within the <'li'> not having its own containing element, so I wrapped the text within a <'span'> element & this appears to fix the form minimising issue however now the 'active' class isn't getting removed (assuming its now a child selector issue??).

https://jsfiddle.net/avk7e30a/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of event bubbling to the `li`. The click events on the `input` are bubbled up to the `li` element and the event handler is executed again. To stop this from happening, use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) on child elements event handlers.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/os883y47/1/)

Add following code

```
$('.active-panel').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stop event from bubbling up
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.options-list li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  $('.active-panel').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.options-list {
  border: 1px solid #d5d6d7;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.option {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
  font: 16px/56px avenir_65regular !important;
  color: #333;
}
.options-list .option.active {
  color: #004ebc;
}
.options-list .option.active:before {
  background-color: #004ebc !important;
  border: 5px solid #83ace0 !important;
}
.options-list .option:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 5px solid #004ebc;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
.panel {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d6d7;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  /* opacity: 0; */
  /* transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear; */
}
.option.active > .panel {
  /* visibility: visible; */
  /* opacity: 1; */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="options-list">
  <li class="option active">FORM FIELD 1
    <div class="panel active-panel">
      <div class="form-field">
        <label class="form-label black">Sub Field</label>
        <input class="form-input" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-field flt">
        <label class="form-label black">Sub Field</label>
        <input class="form-input half" type="text" />
        <input class="form-input half" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-field flt">
        <label class="form-label black cvc">Sub Field</label>
        <input class="form-input half" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="option">FORM FIELD 2
    <div class="panel"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="option">FORM FIELD 3
    <div class="panel"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Read: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: Perfect! Wasn't aware of the bubbling issue..Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

HTML is the same.

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.options-list li').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.options-list').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/os883y47/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following code as the first statements in your handler, so it only continues if the click was on a direct child (`li`) of the `.options-list` element:

```
$('.options-list li').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).parent().is('.options-list')) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afd3gub1/1/).

Comment: This is something you hard-code to a specific element. If the element changes in future and the class remains the same, it functions wrong

Comment: Yes, but the handler itself is already on `li` in the original code. But I have altered the code to check for the parent class.

Comment: True but if it has a child `li`, and a click event is triggeres on it, then it goes wrong

Comment: That's another thing. I have just updated the code to check for the parent class. Of course, if they get nested, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following

```
$(function() {
    $('.options-list li').click(function(e){
        if (e.target === this) {
           $(this).toggleClass('active');
           $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

This is because, you added click event to the parent, so even when you click its children the event get triggered. So a validation is required to confirm it is parent element

Answer (score 0):

You may want to prevent the click-event on the panels:

JavaScript

```
$('.options-list li .panel').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/aq14wmv7/)